# Round Raster to next higher or lower int

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, arcgis-desktop

I am using ArcGIS 10.1.

I am searching for a solution to calculate a raster.
The values are like:
0.2
0.6
5.3
i.e.
How can I now get 0.2 as 0 and 0.6 to 1 and 5.3 to 5? In the end integer numbers.
The "roundup" and "rounddown" functions are worse to do this.

Thanks for any hints.

Luigi

Comment: I know this might be late but does `int(yourraster + 0.5)` really give the result? I think what it does is that it simply strips the decimal place (rounding down always). So if you use `int(5.9)` it will simply return `5` as the result. But shouldn't a round function yield `6` as result? In Python, the function `int(round(5.9,0))` will yield `5` as a result, but not sure how this is achieved within the raster calculator of ArcGIS.

Comment: No, `Int(raster + 0.5)` will round up or down to the nearest integer, not truncate down. i.e `int(5.9 + 0.5)` is equivalent to `int(6.4)` which equals `6`. In python, try: `print int(5.9 + 0.5)`. Python will print `6`. Your comment that "in Python... `int(round(5.9,0))` will yield `5`" is also incorrect, it will return `6`.

Comment: I wonder how to round the raster cell values in Python?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/88645)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Int(yourraster + 0.5)` will round to the nearest integer.

For rasters that may contain negative values:

```
Con(yourraster < 0, Int(yourraster - 0.5), Int(yourraster + 0.5))
```

Comment: This only works if your raster contains positive values only.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple values to reclassify from a single raster then I suggest to use "arcpy.sa.Reclassify" tool. For example:

```
outras = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(inras,"Value",RemapValue([0.2,0],[0.6,1],[5.3,5]),"DATA")
```

Comment: Although this method is very flexible, it is *much* harder, more error-prone, and more time-consuming than Luke's answer.

Comment: Not my solution. ;-)