# Rounding raster pixel values to one decimal place in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, raster-conversion

I have single band raster whose values somehow were set to something like `1.399999999` instead of `1.4`, `1.29999999999` instead of `1.3` (I'm not sure about the number of 9's there.), `1.2000047683` instead of `1.2`. While some pixels do have a value `0.5`.
I actually need all values to one decimal place like`0.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4`. For this I searched around and bumped into [one answer in stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206724/rounding-raster-values-in-qgis-raster-calculator). I did not find `gdal.calc` as suggested but found `r.mapcalculator` (dialog box looked similar). I then used the function `round(A,1)`. But it did not work.

How can I round the pixel values to one decimal place ?

When I used raster calculator `raster@1 * 100` the new raster formed has values like `50, 120, 130, 140` and then again used `newraster@1 / 100` to obtain `0.5, 1.20000047683, 1.299999999, 1.399999999`.

Comment: You can multiply by 10, then convert to integer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis?rq=1 and then back to float and divide by 10

Comment: which raster should I multiply by 10 ? The one with values 1.3999999 ? @BERA

Comment: @BERA Yes, Sorry about that. From the link you posted, this line gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 E:/float.tif E:/int.tif converts to int. Now what do I use to convert it back to int ? Is it FLT ?

Comment: @BERA It was Float32, but It didnot work. It gave me back 1.399999 and 1.299999

Comment: It worked with Float 64 just fine :D Thank you! @BERA

Comment: The banner that you have included within your question, which I think is poor practice, says in many more words "I don't think this is a duplicate".  If you do not think that it is a duplicate please start your question with something more like "I have reviewed <question link> and I do not think that it is the same as the question that I am about to ask because ...".  Please don't skimp on detail as to why you think that your question is a new one because the community (via one of its elected moderators, in this case) has already expressed that they think it is.

Comment: Also, for questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply by 10, then convert to integer using gdal_translate, see: [How to round pixel values of a raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/how-to-round-pixel-values-of-a-raster-in-qgis?rq=1) and then back to float and divide by 10.

To convert to Int:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 E:/float.tif E:/int.tif
```

To convert back to Float:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float64 E:/int.tif E:/float64.tif
```