# Using gdal_translate to round pixel values in raster - I'm getting an error

Tags: qgis, convert, gdal-translate, raster-conversion

I tried to follow along at question: [Rounding raster pixel values to one decimal place in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280185/rounding-raster-pixel-values-to-one-decimal-place-in-qgis)

but my python script throws a syntax error at GTiff. I do have one that works for ArcGIS but my end users need the Spatial Analyst extension and does not have budget to buy it. So here I am trying this way.

What is going wrong?

I am a rookie.

```
# Import required modules
# Python modules

import sys
import time
import os
# Qgis modules
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings

gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 H:/test/ytest1.tif H:/test/output/int.tif

#done
print("done")
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the gdal_translate command from command line?

Comment: `gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 H:/test/ytest1.tif H:/test/output/int.tif` is not python syntax, it is commandline syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run gdal_translate in a python script, you can use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to call the gdal_translate utility on the command line.

You should replace this line:

```py
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 H:/test/ytest1.tif H:/test/output/int.tif
```

with this:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([
    "gdal_translate", "-of", "GTiff", "-ot", "Int32", 
    "H:/test/ytest1.tif", "H:/test/output/int.tif"
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!