# Round raster values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, decimal-points

I would like to reduce the number of decimal places of my raster to one. Currently they appear like that: 3.963322230. The solution that I have found online works well to get integer values but not to reduce the number of decimal places (see here [Rounding pixel values of raster in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/rounding-pixel-values-of-raster-in-qgis)). I have already tried with gdal raster calculator as explained here:
[Rounding raster values in QGIS raster calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206724/rounding-raster-values-in-qgis-raster-calculator)

I have also tried the 'round raster' tool, but nothing has changed.

It seems the number of decimal places of a raster cannot be changed, at least in qgis

Comment: What expression did you try with the raster calculator, and what was the result? Please add it to your question body, as well as the output format and data type.

Comment: Potential duplicate of: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206724/rounding-raster-values-in-qgis-raster-calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206724/rounding-raster-values-in-qgis-raster-calculator)

Comment: yes I have tried this solution but it doesn't work if I use round(A,1) or round_(A,1) or floor(A,1) with gdal raster calculator.

Comment: What exactly is your result with that and how is it not working?

Comment: @enolan: here we speak about raster layer, not vector layer.

Comment: @bugmenot123 my result is always a raster but the number of decimal places did not change

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "number of decimals"? Please be concrete, maybe with an example. Do the values change?

Comment: The values of my raster have 16 decimal places, for example 3.8720101092912356 but I would like to have just one (in this case 3.9). When I used the suggested solution, the result is still a raster with 16 decimals.