# Rounding pixel values of raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, pixel, integer

I have a raster with float number values for example: 2.544459104537964 and I want to round these up to integers. I have seen other posts on ArcGIS like [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/round-raster-to-next-higher-or-lower-int) but when I use Raster Calculator in QGIS, `Int(myraster + 0.5)` only makes the first value (which is 0) to 0,5 and the last one (which is 100) to 100,5. The other pixels stay float.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but it works:
The QGIS raster calculator does not support rounding as far as I know but you can use GDAL to perform `float` to `int` type conversions.

1. Raster -> Conversion -> Translate

- change the datatype from float to int by using the `-ot` option
- `gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 E:/float.tif E:/int.tif`

edit: This answer was written while Qgis 2.0 was the latest major version - please see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403192/39299) where to find the command in QGis 3.0

Comment: OMG this worked perfectly! Values such as 3,391823765 are now 3 and values like 5,912735176253 are now 6! thank you so so so much

Comment: Wait, so it doesn't allways round down? Am I missing something in the documentation here?

Comment: To me it rounds them up as it should: 0,5 and above decimal becomes 1 and 0,4 and below becomes 0! And actually, after that I wanted the image to be grayscale. At first I typed -ot Int32 as you said, but then I had issues with the image in image processing software like Gimp. It showed as a 1 band RGBA. So I searched the documentation and I tried -ot Byte. Then it worked like a charm. Thanks again for this!

Comment: Perfectly! I have already read many answers and no one did correctly operation. Thank you.

Comment: odd that QGIS doesnt have that option in the dialog box

Comment: Could you please explain how and where you apply the "gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Int32 E:/float.tif E:/int.tif". I do not understand how and where you apply that,
Ernest

Comment: @ErnestDunwoody Either in QGIS under the "Raster" menu point or directly from the command line with GDAL installed (e.g. the OSGEO4W shell)

Comment: I tried to use that command line, but the output raster has wrong values. I had values from 4,39366 to 77,63357, now integers are from -2147483648 to 64. Any clue about this ?

Comment: @J.Delannoy this would require more information about the precise software versions you are using, the command and maybe a subset of the data you tried to convert.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My version is GDAL 2.3.2 (09/18). The command is the one in your answer. The pixel values have 6 decimals, ex : 10,189230.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Round Raster`:

> This algorithm rounds the cell values of a raster dataset according to
> the specified number of decimals.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by @Kersten is still good six years on. I didn't get it right first time though, so just to save anyone else similar problems, here are some more details for QGIS 3.10. The tool is currently in `Toolbox > GDAL > Raster conversion > Translate (convert format)`. The `-ot` option goes in the dialogue box, but you also need to specify the data type you want to convert to. Like so:

[image]

Other options are available:

[image]
Source - https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#translate-convert-format

Answer (score 2):

**Update February 2022:**

The QGIS raster calculator doesn't support rounding or data formats (which is annoying), but the gdal raster calculator does **(it supports rounding, data formats and even more important in my opinion: Compression)**! It is usually available in QGIS as well, but easily overlooked if you don't know it's there (Search for "calc"):

[image: Processing Toolbox showing Raster Calculator]

The gdal Calculator (gdal_calc) supports calculations in numpy style and also all gdal data format options. It just isn't as comfortable on the interface and limited to 6 different input rasters (as far as I can see). You have to manually select input files from a loaded layers drop down menu/file location, select the input Band and type your formula with placeholders `A, B ... F` for input files (i.e. bands of files). The configurations looks as follows and results in a gdal command as shown below:

[image: Gdal Calculator Interface]

```
gdal_calc.bat --calc "A-B" 
    --format GTiff --type Int16 
    -A "in_file_A.tif"--A_band 1 
    -B "in_file_B.tif" --B_band 1 
    --co COMPRESS=DEFLATE --co PREDICTOR=2 --co ZLEVEL=9 
    --outfile "outfile.tif"
```