# Converting float32 format raster in integer type raster

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, floating-point, integer

To load my landscape map on Graphab, my raster needs to be in the format "integer type". However, it is in float32 format and I can't manage to convert it. I am using QGIS.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Mayo's answer is what I would use.  Here's some more discussion that covers rounding of the values as well.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146543/rounding-pixel-values-of-raster-in-qgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the GDAL [Translate](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdaltranslate) algorithm, leave all the parameters as default, just change the Output data type parameter (in the lower part of the algorithm dialog) to the desired data type.
[image: 2]

And the data types form the QGIS [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#id18):

> Defines the data type of the output raster file. Options:
>
> - 0 - Use Input Layer Data Type
> - 1 - Byte (Eight bit unsigned integer (quint8))
> - 2 - Int16 (Sixteen bit signed integer (qint16))
> - 3 - UInt16 (Sixteen bit unsigned integer (quint16))
> - 4 - UInt32 (Thirty two bit unsigned integer (quint32))
> - 5 - Int32 (Thirty two bit signed integer (qint32))
> - 6 - Float32 (Thirty two bit floating point (float))
> - 7 - Float64 (Sixty four bit floating point (double))
> - 8 - CInt16 (Complex Int16)
> - 9 - CInt32 (Complex Int32)
> - 10 - CFloat32 (Complex Float32)
> - 11 - CFloat64 (Complex Float64)
> - 12 - Int8 (Eight bit signed integer (qint8))